# date format issue with asp.net and sql server

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, date

when i'm inserting data to the sql server 2008 database through asp.net application date inserted to the database in the following format

> "10 june 2011"

this is wrong and i need "dd/mm/yyyy" or "yyyy/mm/dd" format to be inserted.why does this happen

Comment: Post your code where you set the date to be sent to the database. You can choose any format that you like.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your data type on the database side is either `datetime` or `date` (on sql server 2008), it shouldn't matter whether you insert the date as `'10 june 2011'` or as `'6/10/2011'` or as `'2011-06-10'`. If you see the data actually being displayed as `'10 June 2011'` that's more likely because your data type is `varchar` or `nvarchar`. If that's the case and the field is only meant to hold dates, I would advise you to change the data type to be actually a `datetime` or `date`.

Answer (score 0):

Use `DateTime.TryParseExact()` method to parse the date.

```
string inputDate="10 June 2011";
string []format ={ "dd MMMM yyyy","dd MMM yyyy"};
DateTime date;

if (DateTime.TryParseExact(inputDate, format, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, 
                           DateTimeStyles.None, out date))
 {
     Console.WriteLine("Valid " + date);
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Table column datatype was Nvarchar, so that it saves data in the above format which is wrong.  By running the following I have solved my issue

```
SET DATEFORMAT DMY;

ALTER TABLE #tmpTest ALTER COLUMN MyCol DATE;
```

Comment: I think the right thing to do here would be to set the answer @Icarus posted as the accepted answer because it appears that the direction he gave you actually solved the problem ... would that not be true?